# R&OS PDF in PHP (name of pdf)

Tags: php, html, pdf, pdf-generation

anyone uses this function to create PDF in PHP?

http://www.ros.co.nz/pdf/

I need set the name of this pdf, and I don't find the option.
The name is the same of the current page; for example if the page is www.myweb.com/hello.php the name will be hello.pdf. I need change this name with an unique name for each pdf because it is for billing.

This is an example of the code:

```
<?php
include('class.ezpdf.php');
$pdf =& new Cezpdf('a4');
$pdf->selectFont('fonts/courier.afm');
$datacreator = array (
                    'Title'=>'Factura PDF',
                    'Author'=>'Just me',
                    'Subject'=>'Factura nº123123123',
                    'Creator'=>'Just me',
                    'Producer'=>'http://www.xxxxxxx.com'
                    );
$pdf->addInfo($datacreator);
$pdf->ezText("<b>Factura numero 123123123 </b>\n",20);
$pdf->ezText("Esta es una prueba de pdf\n",12);
$pdf->ezText("\n\n\n",10);
$pdf->ezText("<b>Fecha:</b> ".date("d/m/Y"),10);
$pdf->ezText("<b>Hora:</b> ".date("H:i:s")."\n\n",10);
$pdf->ezStream();
?>
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `$pdf->ezStream()` or `$pdf->stream()`, use `$pdf->output()` instead.
Try to add following codes to the bottom of your PHP code:

```
header("Content-type:application/pdf");
header("Content-Disposition:attachment;filename=yourfilename.pdf");
print $pdf->output();
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: ezStream method has been fixed a while ago. So alternatively you can also use `$pdf->ezStream(['Content-Disposition'=>'readme.pdf']);`

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, the filename can only be set via http headers and the author of the library is not sure whether it works or not. The [documention for stream()](http://www.ros.co.nz/pdf/readme.pdf) states:

> The options array can be used to set a number of things about the output:
>
> 'Content-Disposition'=>'filename' sets the filename, though not too sure how well this will work as
>   in my trial the browser seems to use the filename of the php file with .pdf on the end.

Answer (score 0):

This might work (not tested though):

Based on [the FAQ](http://www.ros.co.nz/pdf/faq.php), `$pdfcode = $pdf->ezOutput();` makes the PDF's code itself. Write it to a whatever.pdf file where whatever is the desired file.

Answer (score 0):

The documentation said to do like this: `$pdf->ezStream(array('filename'=>$nome,'compress'=>0));` but, nothing happen for me.