# Generate multiple PDF files in loop in php

Tags: php

I want to create multiple pdf files using loop .
I am putting code as below but only one file is generated and all data are written in that file only.How to generate multiple files.

My code is ..

```
for($i=0;$i<4;$i++)
{

$pli_ids=explode(",",$string);
foreach($pli_ids as $id)
{

    $data[]=array('inv_no'=>$inv_obj->invoice_number,'Work_order'=>'gandalf','data_type'=>$pli_obj->data_type_c_pl_c,'subscription'=>'subs1','hs_code'=>'hs1');
}
require_once ('include/pdf/class.ezpdf.php');
$pdf =& new Cezpdf();   
$pdf->selectFont('include/fonts/Helvetica.afm');

$pdf->ezSetY(750);
$pdf->ezText(date('d:M:Y'),14); $pdf->ezSetY(720);
$pdf->ezText('To,',14); $pdf->ezSetY(690);
$pdf->ezText('Mr. Kumar {contact Name}',14); $pdf->ezText('Kunal And Company Ltd {Account Name}',14);
$pdf->ezText('No 6, IInd Floor Marine Drive {contact shipping address}',14);$pdf->ezSetY(610);
$pdf->ezText('Mumbai, Pin: 560079',14); $pdf->ezText('Maharashtra',14);$pdf->ezText('Mob.:9977200030',14);
$pdf->ezSetY(550);
$pdf->ezText(' <c:uline>Sub.: Your order of Export Import News </c:uline> ',15);
$pdf->ezSetY(520);  
$pdf->ezText('Dear Mr. Kumar, {Customer Name}',14);
$pdf->ezSetY(490);
$pdf->ezText('Greetings for the day!.',14); $pdf->ezSetY(460);
$pdf->ezText('Thanks for being a valuable customer of Infodrive India,we have enclosed the data as follows.');
$pdf->ezSetY(430);  
$pdf->ezTable($data,array('inv_no'=>'Inv No.','Work_order'=>'Work Order non','data_type'=>'Data Type','subscription'=>'subscription','hs_code'=>'HS Code'),
    '',
    array('showHeadings'=>2,'shaded'=>1,'xPos'=>'right','xOrientation'=>'left','width'=>400));
$filename = "pdf_".$i;
$pdf->ezStream(array("Content-Disposition"=>$filename));

}
```

Comment: What do you expect this script to do? Output multiple pdf files to a browser? You should write them to some directory and present them as downloads, or create an archive with all of them inside. Not pump them to the user's browser

Answer (score 0):

You are using `ezStream()` to send the pdf to the browser. You can only send one file that way.

Comment: Hi MR. Jeroen Moons       any way will be useful for me . how to save all pdfs in a folder ?

Comment: Oh, hey look, with little effort (that you should be putting in, not me), I found [this SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9497344/ros-pdf-in-php-name-of-pdf). You might also want to consider using a PHP PDF library that isn't so hard to find information about, too.

Comment: Docs: http://pdf-php.sourceforge.net/pdf-php/readme.php use `ezOutput()` with Output Buffering to capture the output http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.outcontrol.php

Comment: when i am using below code , then also only one pdf is generated and its not opening also.                                                 header("Content-type:application/pdf");
 header("Content-Disposition:attachment;filename=$filename.pdf");
 print $pdf->ezOutput();

Comment: @RakeshRay I already told you: "You can only send one file that way". If you want multiple files you have to save them on the server and send them one at a time.